# Differences in Magento versions

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento2.2

What are the differences between all the Magento versions

- Magento2.0
- Magento2.1
- Magento Open Source 2.2
- Magento Commerce 2.2
- Magento Commerce Cloud 2.2

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.9CE.html
Here you can get all details, changelog about all version of magento. 
Magento have provided all information in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Open Source 2.2 => **Magento Community**

Magento Commerce 2.2 => **Magento Enterprice**

Magento Commerce Cloud 2.2 => **Magento Enterprice Cloud**